# P-Table Multiple selection using checkboxes [PrimeNG]

Tags: angular, primeng

I need help with "Multiple selection (click + shift)" I cannot understand how to make it works on checkboxes.

In the docs there is an example "Checkbox Selection" and note *"Multiple selection can also be handled using checkboxes by enabling the selectionMode property of column as "multiple".*

And example from docs:

```
<p-table [value]="products" [(selection)]="selectedProducts3" dataKey="code" responsiveLayout="scroll">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 3rem">
                <p-tableHeaderCheckbox></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
            </th>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-product>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p-tableCheckbox [value]="product"></p-tableCheckbox>
            </td>
            <td>{{product.code}}</td>
            <td>{{product.name}}</td>
            <td>{{product.category}}</td>
            <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

But when I try to add this property 'selectionMode' it still doesn't work.

My new example:

```
<p-table [value]="products" [(selection)]="selectedProducts3" dataKey="code" responsiveLayout="scroll"
         selectionMode="multiple"> // <--------- Added line with selectionMode property
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 3rem">
            <p-tableHeaderCheckbox></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
        </th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-product>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p-tableCheckbox [value]="product"></p-tableCheckbox>
        </td>
        <td>{{product.code}}</td>
        <td>{{product.name}}</td>
        <td>{{product.category}}</td>
        <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

I think there is some silly mistake but I'm new to PrimeNG, so will be tanksful for any help.

Here is there [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tableselection-demo-bdmtkn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `metaKeySelection` property as true to enable multiple selection with `(click + shift)`
And to make the rows selectable, use `pSelectableRow` and `pSelectableRowIndex` properties.

Here is the code after modifying it:

```html
<p-table
    [value]="products"
    [(selection)]="selectedProducts3"
    dataKey="code"
    selectionMode="multiple"
    [metaKeySelection]="true"
  >
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 3rem">
          <p-tableHeaderCheckbox></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
        </th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <!-- others -->
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-product let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
      <tr [pSelectableRow]="product" [pSelectableRowIndex]="rowIndex">
        <td>
          <p-tableCheckbox
            [value]="product"
          ></p-tableCheckbox>
        </td>
        <td>{{ product.code }}</td>
        <!-- others -->
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```